# Change in compiler, not the framework - Is a full cycle test needed?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, testing

We've a long running project which is under development in **VS 2008** and **.NET Framework 3.5**. The software has gone through many test cycles. We're still adding features, fixing bugs etc. A full cycle test (testing every feature - 6 weeks of testing for one person) was also done many days ago. Now, when a new feature is added or some bugs are fixed, only relevant portion gets tested before new release.

We're planning to gradually start using **VS 2010**. The software will still run in **.NET Framework 3.5**. As far as I understand, as we'll be using a new compiler *which may compile same code differently**, the next release of the software in new compiler must pass through a full cycle test despite it will run under the same Framework.

Is a full cycle testing really necessary in this case?

**I don't have enough experience to be certain, I just feel it may happen.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you must retest.  There are some [breaking changes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee855831.aspx) in the C# 4.0 compiler, and while some of them only apply to framework 4.0, others apply to any framework.  For example, you might find differences in overload resolution.

**EDIT**

The /langversion compiler option does not get around this.  Its [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f4ckecs0.aspx) says "Because each version of the C# compiler contains extensions to the language specification, /langversion does not give you the equivalent functionality of an earlier version of the compiler."

Comment: From question: "Will still run in [target] .NET Framework 3.5". Does the above still apply? Alternatively, "is there way to ensure C#3-only in VS2010"?

Comment: @pst yes there is a way to ensure c# 3. See my answer.

Comment: @pst, no there is no way to ensure equivalence with the earlier version of the compiler; see the edited answer.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using C# version 3.0 as earlier then Not. You can enforce this by going to "Project Properties" > Build > Advanced and setting "Language Version"

As you have mentioned its only the development environment you are upgrading not the Framework, hence the MSIL will be the same. With the same code being executed you do not need the full life cycle of testing.

The code(IL or assembly) given to client in assemblies is no different as the underlying compiler will be same.

**Update:** By default C# version which will be used is 4.0, which have breaking changes as [phoog](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8830678/293712) has mentioned. In this case you will have to retest the application.

Comment: Actually the code might be slightly different as emitted by the compiler, but it has 100% the same meaning/semantics.

Comment: @leppie see my answer for a link to Microsoft's page on breaking changes in the C# 4.0 compiler.

Comment: @phoog Even if OP uses c# 4.0 but they do not use new features of c# 4.0 its as good as C# 3.0 build.

Comment: @Maheep see the edited answer for a link to the documentation for the /langversion option.  The /langversion switch applies to syntax accepted by the compiler.  It doesn't claim to make the compiler use older versions of the overload resolution algorithm.  The newer compiler takes optional parameters into account when resolving overload candidates; there's no indication that the /langversion switch would change this.

Comment: @Maheep besides, even if Microsoft claimed that the VS 2010 compiler *could* reproduce the behavior of the VS 2008 compiler, would you trust them?  They are not infallible.  It's entirely possible that the OP's application exposes some new bug in the new compiler that their testing did not uncover.  If you haven't done so already, start reading Eric Lippert's posts here and on his blog.  He frequently discusses bugs in Microsoft's code, many of which he introduced himself.  He and the rest of the C# team are very smart, but they do make mistakes.