# Make .net 4 application compatible on .net 3.5

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I have created a winform application in Visual Studio (i.e. .net 4.0). Whenever i try to install my application with .net 3.5 it asks to install .net 4.0.
How can I make my application compatible on .net 3.5 platform. I have tried changing the Target framework to 3.5 and removing the prerequisites of .net 4.0, but it does not works. Can you suggest me on how to achieve the same?

Comment: is your install configured properly now that you changed the target framework?

Comment: so do I need to change any thing in setup project too?

Comment: Why changing of target framework didn't work? What happened?

Comment: no it didn't work. The same procedure of installing .net 4.0 starts whenever i try to install my application.

Comment: did you change the target framework both in the setup and application?

Comment: In application I have changed the target framework but not in setup project. Can you please suggest how to change target framework in setup project?

Comment: If the best you can tell us is "it's not working" the best we can tell you is "you missed a step." What steps, exactly, did you take?

Comment: First i changed Target platform to 3.5 in the application then removed the prerequisite of .net4.0 in application. Then removed the prerequsite of .net4.0 from setup project. Still it asks for .net 4.0 while installing my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of struggle, I finally got the root cause of my issue. I am posting the solution so that others would not have to do any struggle to do this job. After changing the Target framework and prerequisites, check for the dependencies in the setup project. Just follow these steps to get to the desired result:

1. Double click on the dependencies of the setup project.
2. Click on the .Net Framework
3. And you will see the Property window will get enabled.
4. Change the Version property to your desired .net Framework ( in my case 3.5).
5. and build your setup again.

Hope this will help others.

Answer (score 1):

Maheep is correct - you need to switch to .Net framework 3.5 as you project target framework. There is no difference between C#.net 4.0 and vb.Net 4.0  - once built and released, both become .Net version 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use C# 4.0 you will need framework 4.0. If you can switch to c# 3.0 then see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8830241/293712)

Answer (score 0):

Check Project Properties -> Publish -> "Prerequisites..."

And also this can be useful: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668079.aspx (especially section "You Have Re-Targeted a Project to a Different Version of the .NET Framework").